# How should I make a "back button" to switch JPanels on a main JFrame class work with multiple JPanel classes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I'm currently working on a game for school, and I've hit a brick wall. I've created a main class that sets up the JFrame, and in that JFrame have JPanel buttons that open a server JPanel class, a client JPanel class, and buttons for options, and exiting the game. Now where I'm stuck is how I should make buttons to go back to the main JPanel using a back button on the server/client JPanel class. Here's the code I have at the moment:

MainUI.class (a different class runs this):

```
public class MainUI extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;

public MainUI() {
    // Sets up the frame
    setTitle("Pong Legacy | Prototype v0.1.0");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    // Starts the Server window
    JButton btnStartServer = new JButton("Start Server");
    btnStartServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel server = new ServerUI();
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            getContentPane().add(server);
            getContentPane().validate();
            getContentPane().repaint();
        }
    });
    btnStartServer.setBounds(97, 364, 100, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnStartServer);

    // Starts the Client window
    JButton btnStartClient = new JButton("Start Client");
    btnStartClient.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel client = new ClientUI();
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            getContentPane().add(client);
            getContentPane().validate();
            getContentPane().repaint();
        }
    });
    btnStartClient.setBounds(97, 400, 100, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnStartClient);

    // Opens the Options menu 
    // (To Do)
    JButton btnOptions = new JButton("Options");
    btnOptions.setBounds(37, 436, 100, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnOptions);

    // Quits the game
    JButton btnQuitGame = new JButton("Quit Game");
    btnQuitGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btnQuitGame.setBounds(157, 436, 100, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnQuitGame);

    // Username Field
    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
    lblUsername.setBounds(121, 45, 52, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblUsername);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(104, 67, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
}
}
```

ServerUI.class:

```
public class MainUI extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;

public MainUI() {
    // Sets up the frame
    setTitle("Pong Legacy | Prototype v0.1.0");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    // Starts the Server window
    JButton btnStartServer = new JButton("Start Server");
    btnStartServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel server = new ServerUI();
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            getContentPane().add(server);
            getContentPane().validate();
            getContentPane().repaint();
        }
    });
    btnStartServer.setBounds(97, 364, 100, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnStartServer);

    // Starts the Client window
    JButton btnStartClient = new JButton("Start Client");
    btnStartClient.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel client = new ClientUI();
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            getContentPane().add(client);
            getContentPane().validate();
            getContentPane().repaint();
        }
    });
    btnStartClient.setBounds(97, 400, 100, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnStartClient);

    // Opens the Options menu 
    // (To Do)
    JButton btnOptions = new JButton("Options");
    btnOptions.setBounds(37, 436, 100, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnOptions);

    // Quits the game
    JButton btnQuitGame = new JButton("Quit Game");
    btnQuitGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    btnQuitGame.setBounds(157, 436, 100, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnQuitGame);

    // Username Field
    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username:");
    lblUsername.setBounds(121, 45, 52, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblUsername);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(104, 67, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
}
 }
```

ClientUI.class:

```
public class ClientUI extends JPanel {

private JTextField textField;

public ClientUI() {
    setLayout(null);

    JButton btnConnect = new JButton("Connect");
    btnConnect.setBounds(47, 400, 200, 25);
    add(btnConnect);

    JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");
    btnBack.setBounds(117, 436, 60, 25);
    add(btnBack);

    JRadioButton rdbtnSelectAServer = new JRadioButton("Select a server from the list:");
    rdbtnSelectAServer.setBounds(66, 25, 161, 25);
    add(rdbtnSelectAServer);

    JRadioButton rdbtnManualConnection = new JRadioButton("Manual Connection:");
    rdbtnManualConnection.setBounds(87, 325, 120, 25);
    add(rdbtnManualConnection);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(47, 355, 200, 25);
    add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
}
}
```

I've heard that I could use a CardLayout, too, but I want to see if I can do it this way.

Comment: `"I've heard that I could use a CardLayout, too, but I want to see if I can do it this way."` -- and you could do it with machine code too, but for my money, I'd use the best tool for the job, and that would be CardLayout.

Comment: Agree with above. I would also suggest you don't use a null layout and the setBounds() method. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm trying to sleep here :P

Comment: You need some kind of model or controller who knows the path the user has taken and how to best to handle a "back" request...